# How to detect FTP file transfer completion?

Tags: perl, ftp, transfer

I am writing a script that polls an FTP site for files and downloads them locally as and when available. The files are deposited to the FTP site randomly by various source parties. I need a way to be able to detect if the file on the FTP site has been transferred over completely by the source party, before downloading them. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: This is a pretty common problem. I solved it once, although not very elegantly, by checking the size of a file, and later checking it again. If the size changes in a 5 second window, probably still writing. I tried locks -- no good.

Comment: P.S. I also processed them oldest first, so the only time I had to wait was on the newest file or three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot manipulate the FTP server itself the only way of checking that comes to my mind is polling the filesize and if the filesize doesn't change for a longer time you can be quite sure the upload has finished. But nobody can guarantee. Ideally you can adapt the FTP server and make it execute some script after finishing some upload.

Some pseudo-code:

```
my %filesizes;
my %processed;

sub poll {
    foreach (@files_on_ftp) {
         if($_->filesize == $filesizes{$_->filename} and not $processed{$_->filename}) {
             process($_);
             $processed{$_->filename)++;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have control over the client, a much safer, cleaner and efficient way is to have the client do the following:

1. Upload the file to ..../partial/somefile
2. Rename ..../partial/somefile to ..../complete/somefile

This causes the file to appear in the latter directory all at once, so all you have to do is scan that directory. You could even ask the OS to be notified of additions to that directory if you wanted a non-polling solution.

Answer (score 2):

Like ikegami's solution depends mine of client side:

1. first is file uploaded
2. if it is completed, client uploads empty flag-file (like `file.name.txt.finished`)

When you see `finished`-file, you know file is ready.