# Detecting whether a file is complete or partial in PHP

Tags: php, upload, copy

In this system, SFTP will be used to upload large video files to a specific directory on the server. I am writing a PHP script that will be used to copy completely uploaded files to another directory.

My question is, what is a good way to tell if a file is completely uploaded or not? I considered taking note of the file size, sleeping the script for a few seconds, reading the size again, and comparing the two numbers. But this seems very kludgy.

Comment: Do you own the software that uploads the file to SFTP or is it done by arbitrary software by user?

Comment: If you don't have complete control over the upload process you can't.

Comment: What OS/server? Is it possible to enumerate open SFTP connections on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, in case you are allowed to run system commands from PHP you can try to get the pids of your sftp server processes with **pidof** command and then use **lsof** output to check if open file descriptors exist for the currently checked upload file.

Answer (score 6):

### Simple

If you just want a simple technique that will handle most use cases - write a process to check the last modified date or (as indicated in the question) the file size and if it hasn't changed in a set time, say 1 minute, assume the upload is finished and process it. Infact - your question is a [near duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625421/how-to-detect-ftp-file-transfer-completion) of another question showing exactly this.

### Robust

An alternative to polling the size/last modified time of a file (which with a slow or intermittent connection could cause an open upload to be considered complete too early) is to listen for when the file has finished being written with [inotify](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php).

[Listening for IN_CLOSE_WRITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070555/linux-how-to-detect-that-ftp-file-upload-is-finished) you can know when an ftp upload has finished updating a specific file.

I've never used it in php, but from the [spartan docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inotify-add-watch.php) it looks that that aught to work in exactly the same way as the underlying lib.

### Make FTP clients work for you

Take into account how some ftp programs work, from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070555/linux-how-to-detect-that-ftp-file-upload-is-finished#comment3145691_3070577):

> it's worth mentioning that some ftp servers create a hidden temporary file to receive data until the transfer is finished. I.e. .foo-ftpupload-2837948723 in the same upload path as the target file

If applicable, from the finished filename you can therefore tell if the ftp upload has actually finished or was stopped/disconnected mid-upload.

Comment: IN_CLOSE_WRITE fires also on broken connections.

Answer (score 1):

During a transfer, the only thing that knows the real size of the file is your SFTP client and maybe the SFTP server (don't know protocol specifics so the server may know too.)  Unless you can talk to the SFTP server directly, then you'll have to wait for the file to finish.  Checking at some interval seems kludgy but under the circumstances is pretty good.  It's what we do on my project.

If you have a very short poll interval, it's not terribly resilient when dealing with uploads that may stall for a few seconds.  So just set the interval to one a minute or something like that.  Assuming you're on a *nix based platform, you could set up a cron job to run every minute (or whatever your polling interval is) to run your script for you.

Answer (score 1):

As @jcolebrand stated - if you have no control over upload process - there is actually not much you can do except guessing (size/date of file). I would look for a server software that allows you to execute hooks/scripts before/after some server action (here: file transfer complete). I am not sure though whether such software exists. As a last resort you could adapt some opensource SFTP server for your requirements by adding such a hook for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting answer was mentioned in a commend under original question (but for some unknown reason the comment was deleted): you can try parsing SFTP server logs to find files that were uploaded completely.